# Where to customise IBOutlets

Tags: ios, objective-c, iboutlet

Where should I customise my `IBOutlets`?

Say I have created a button with interface builder, created an IBOutlet for it and I would want to change a property during runtime (ex: background color or localized title).

<strike>I would think of adding it to the `viewDidLoad` method, but outlets aren't yet created.</strike> 
I remember having nil outlets in `viewDidLoad`, but I might be wrong.

If I move it `viewWillAppear`, the code will be executed every time the view controller's view appears.

Is there any better place for my `IBOutlet` related code, so it's only executed once?

---

Obviously I can do just about any customization using only the interface builder and making use of the `User defined runtime attributes` or localized stroryboards, but I don't like that since it's much more tedious to change later.

Comment: I would think of adding it to the viewDidLoad method, but outlets aren't yet created.???

Comment: Aren't they? If I create an IBOutlet property to a UILabel, it will be nil in viewDidLoad, won't it?

Comment: @Lord Zsolt No, you are wrong. When viewDidLoad is executed the whole view with its subviews has been loaded and IBOutlets are pointing to their respective elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Doc

[image]

Its clearly says about the Views loaded into the memory in the `-viewDidLoad()` delegate itself.

Comment: **I clearly remember  having nil outlets in viewDidLoad**, then check the IBOutlet Connnections or something, you'd missed.

Answer (score 1):

> I would think of adding it to the viewDidLoad method, but outlets
>   aren't yet created.

It is a false statement, Because you only get the `viewDidLoad:` message after IBOutlets are created. So you can safely do any customization in `viewDidLoad:`

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say you have a Button you want to customise. You put the button at the place where you want it to be and then open the “Identity Inspector” on the right.

There is a textfield for “Custom Class”:

[image: Textfield for CustomClass]

I usually create a subclass of UIButton / NSButton (depending on iOS or OSX) and edit the behaviour, drawing methods and functionality in this class file. Then just add the name of this class in this textfield. Voila!

Comment: A little bit tedious to have a different class for each button.

Comment: Well, you don’t need a different class for each button? If you’re doing it right it should be one for your buttons...

Comment: For example considering localization. That means a different sort of customization for each button, so you need to have something above the button (a controller) which handles them.

Comment: Localization is a bad example because of NSLocalizedString, which should take care of almost all the work for you. Let’s say you have 2 different styles of buttons. A round one and a rectangle. You could then edit the drawing code of one button class in a way, that a flag decides if the button is round or a rectangle. This way you are even more flexible in that you can swap your button style any time you want to, without removing buttons and replacing them.

Comment: You're contradicting your answer with that comment. You're saying to put the customization code into the class. But the flag-handling clearly has to be done outside the class, by a controller. And localization is a valid example, by customization, I asked where to set the localized title for the button (aka calling NSLocalizedString).

Comment: Not necessarily. I do not now your implementation, but since you are talking about IBOutlets, they are _already connected_ to a controller. No need to create a dedicated controller.

Asking your DataController for a background-colour and sending this value to your button shouldn’t be a problem at all.

Comment: By "controller", I meant the view controller the outlet is connected to.